# Invoking a Java WS from PHP using WSO2

Tags: php, wso2

I'm trying to consume a WS over https on a port different from 80 and 443; here is the code:

```
$client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"https://host:5678/...service?WSDL"));
$proxy = $client->getProxy();
$arr_param=array(....);
$return_val = $proxy->method_name($arr_param);
var_dump($return_val);
```

$return_val is always null. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: based on the documentation at http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.0.0/docs/manual.html section 10. Using WSDL . It seems like you are attempting to do the correct thing.  Did you think about grabbing the wsdl separately and using the instructions at section 10.4. WSDL to PHP Code Generation to simplify this process first? Just a thought.